# CoreMotion convert Iphone Pitch: raidians to degrees

Tags: swift, ios8, core-motion

I am trying to convert radians to degrees. I already know:
1 radian = 180/PI This does give me degrees.

You can check out my code here: [github](https://github.com/kyp12/ROM-Test-v1)

Here is my problem:

[image]

I am getting radian data that only goes from 0 to 1.5 and then back to 0 then from 0 to -1.5 and back to 0. So when I do the conversion I get 0 to 90 and back to 0 and then 0 to -90 and back to 0.

What I want is to be able to go from 0 to 360 as I move the pitch of the Iphone. I am pretty sure its an easy map and when I see it i will slam my hand into my forehead.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You problem sounds as if it could be solved by using ``atan2`` instead of ``atan`` somewhere in your code. I quickly looked at your code, but couldn't find something like this, though. Your function ``radiansToDegrees`` looks wrong to me, at least if ``M_PI`` is supposed to contain the value of Pi.

Comment: what should I use for PI then?

Comment: You should change ``var degrees = (radians * M_PI)`` to ``var degrees = radians * (180.0 / M_PI)``, see johnnyclem's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue is a typo.
The function in your repo is:

var degrees = (radians * M_PI)

but as you noted at the beginning of your question, it should be

var degrees = radians * (180.0 / M_PI)